# Confused of how `Box<dyn Fn(Args)>` is interpreted

Tags: rust

I don't really know how to put this question, but can somebody explain why this works:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=969cf50f66746c4aa3941200e01f1570

```
enum SlotFn<'a, Comp, Args = (), R = ()> 
where Args: 'static,
R: Default + 'static,
{
    SimpleFn(fn(Args) -> R),
    MemberFn(fn(&'a Comp) -> R),
    MemberFnMut(fn(&'a mut Comp, Args) -> R),
}

impl<'a, Comp, Args, R> SlotFn<'a, Comp, Args, R> 
where Args: 'static,
R: Default + 'static,{
    fn from_member(f: fn(&'a Comp) -> R) -> Self{
        SlotFn::MemberFn(f)
    }

    fn from_member_mut(f: fn(&'a mut Comp, Args) -> R) -> Self {
        SlotFn::MemberFnMut(f)
    }

    fn emit(&self, comp: &'a Comp, args: Args) -> R {
        match self {
            SlotFn::SimpleFn(f) => f(args),
            SlotFn::MemberFn(f) => f(comp),
            _ => Default::default()
        }
    }

    fn emit_mut(&mut self, comp: &'a mut Comp, args: Args) -> R {
        match self {
            SlotFn::MemberFnMut(f) => f(comp, args),
            _ => Default::default()
        }
    }
}


struct Test(u32);

impl Test {

    fn reffunc(&self) {
        println!("value: {}", self.0);
    }

    fn reffunc_mut(&mut self, val: u32) {
        self.0 = val;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut test = Test(0);
    let slot = SlotFn::from_member(Test::reffunc);
    let mut mslot = SlotFn::from_member_mut(Test::reffunc_mut);

    mslot.emit_mut(&mut test, 10);
    slot.emit(&test, ());
}
```

but not this:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1534d9b49327272ddbbd04826efd644a

```
enum SlotFn<'a, Comp, Args = (), R = ()> 
where Args: 'static,
R: Default + 'static,
{
    SimpleFn(Box<dyn Fn(Args) -> R + Send + Sync + 'static>),
    MemberFn(Box<dyn Fn(&'a Comp) -> R + Send + Sync + 'static>),
    MemberFnMut(Box<dyn FnMut(&'a mut Comp, Args) -> R + Send + Sync + 'static>),
}

impl<'a, Comp, Args, R> SlotFn<'a, Comp, Args, R> 
where Args: 'static,
R: Default + 'static,{
  
    fn from_member<F>(f: F) -> Self where F: Fn(&'a Comp) -> R + Send + Sync + 'static{
        SlotFn::MemberFn(Box::new(f))
    }

    fn from_member_mut<F>(f: F) -> Self where F: FnMut(&'a mut Comp, Args) -> R + Send + Sync + 'static{
        SlotFn::MemberFnMut(Box::new(f))
    }

    fn emit(&self, comp: &'a Comp, args: Args) -> R {
        match self {
            SlotFn::SimpleFn(f) => f(args),
            SlotFn::MemberFn(f) => f(comp),
            _ => Default::default()
        }
    }

    fn emit_mut(&mut self, comp: &'a mut Comp, args: Args) -> R {
        match self {
            SlotFn::MemberFnMut(f) => f(comp, args),
            _ => Default::default()
        }
    }
}


struct Test(u32);

impl Test {

    fn reffunc(&self) {
        println!("value: {}", self.0);
    }

    fn reffunc_mut(&mut self, val: u32) {
        self.0 = val;
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut test = Test(0);
    let slot = SlotFn::from_member(Test::reffunc);
    let mut mslot = SlotFn::from_member_mut(Test::reffunc_mut);

    mslot.emit_mut(&mut test, 10);
    slot.emit(&test, ());
}
```

in the second case, I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `test` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable

mutable borrow might be used here, when `mslot` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `SlotFn<'_, Test, u32>`
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question, provide the error messages and explain the differences. Questions should be answerable without requiring users to follow links. And reduce the example to only the bits that reproduce the problem if possible.

Comment: Also, please provide a *minimal* reproducible example. It might even help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I think this is happening because the second one uses owned values inside the enum variants (`Box`) , whereas the first one uses function pointers, which are static. This seems to allow the exclusive borrow of `test`to end after the line where it is borrowed rather than until the end of the lexical scope. Hopefully someone else can explain why that is, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the `'a` of `from_member()` `'a1`, and the `'a` of `from_member_mut()` `'a2`. If `'a1` and `'a2` overlap, this is an error `test` is mutably borrowed for `'a2` while it is borrowed for `'a1`. So what are `'a1` and `'a2`?

The shortest they can be is from the creation of the `SlotFn` (for each its own `SlotFn`) object to its destruction, because for all that time the `SlotFn` can access the data of `'a`.

In the first code, we can destroy the `SlotFn`s early, because they do not implement `Drop` therefore they cannot perform any action while destroyed, so an early destruction cannot be observed. Therefore, in the first code, the compiler shortens `'a1` and `'a2` just until the `emit_mut()` and `emit()`, respectively, so they do not conflict.

In the second case, however, they may implement `Drop` - `dyn Trait` is always considered as implementing `Drop`, as the compiler cannot know what is inside - and therefore, their lifetimes must end at the end of the block, because `Drop` could observe `'a`. So they conflict.

Comment: I see, so the additional 'static constrain is not considered while drop can happens for one sooner than the other?